# changing temp tables to declaring them

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just a question regards to temp tables and declaring table. If I change the temp tables 'ChangedData' and 'PackageDatatoProcess' to their own variables '@ChangedData' and '@PackageDatatoProcess', can I ask how I am suppose to change the select into statement as I have not quite done this before. Virtually I told that we can declare tables rather than using the select into but just need a bit of help with this:

```
select distinct * into #PackageDataToProcess from #ChangedData pp
        outer apply (
            select pk.Reference, pjl.PackageToJournalLinkId, j.CreatedDate, pccl.PackageCostChangeLogId from Jet2Holidays.dbo.Package pk
            inner join Jet2Holidays.dbo.PackageToJournalLink pjl on pk.PackageId = pjl.PackageId
            inner join Jet2Holidays.dbo.Journal j on pjl.JournalId = j.JournalId
                and j.PrincipalName= iif(@AllowNonSupportChanges = 0, 'HolidaysSupport', j.PrincipalName) 
            inner join Jet2Holidays.dbo.BusinessProcess bp on pjl.BusinessProcessId = bp.BusinessProcessId
                and bp.[Description] =  iif(@AllowNonSupportChanges = 0, 'CallCentreAction', bp.[Description]) 
            left outer join Jet2Holidays.dbo.PackageCostChangeLog pccl on pccl.PackageToJournalLinkId = pjl.PackageToJournalLinkId
            where pk.Reference = pp.PackageReference
            and pp.JournalID = pjl.JournalId

            ) as packageData
```

Comment: "SELECT ... INTO" syntax will create the temp table on the fly. If you decide to use @table variables, then the table has to be declared upfront with correct data types, then use "INSERT INTO ... SELECT" syntax.

Comment: You are aware a temporary table and table variable are not the same?  @ is a table variable.  # is temporary table.

Comment: You cant select into table variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you declare your variable tables like so:

```
DECLARE @PackageDataToProcess TABLE
(
    Reference UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
,   PackageToJournalLinkId INT
,   CreatedDate DATETIME
,   PackageCostChangeLogId INT
,   {other columns here}
)

DECLARE @ChangedData TABLE
(
    Reference UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
,   PackageToJournalLinkId INT
,   CreatedDate DATETIME
,   PackageCostChangeLogId INT
,   {other columns here}
)
```

At this point you can populate your @ChangedData table like so:

```
INSERT @ChangedData ( Reference, PackageToJournalLinkId, CreatedDate, PackageCostChangeLogId, {other columns})
SELECT Reference, PackageToJournalLinkId, CreatedDate, PackageCostChangeLogId, {other columns} 
   FROM ChangedDataSource -- Table, Procedure, Function
```

And then you can run your code by substituting @PackageDataToProcess for #PackageDataToProcess. Here it is again with a slight re-write (from the original):

```
    INSERT @PackageDataToProcess
    select distinct pp.* from @ChangedData pp
    outer apply (
        select pk.Reference, pjl.PackageToJournalLinkId, j.CreatedDate, pccl.PackageCostChangeLogId from Jet2Holidays.dbo.Package pk
        inner join Jet2Holidays.dbo.PackageToJournalLink pjl on pk.PackageId = pjl.PackageId
        inner join Jet2Holidays.dbo.Journal j on pjl.JournalId = j.JournalId
            and j.PrincipalName= iif(@AllowNonSupportChanges = 0, 'HolidaysSupport', j.PrincipalName) 
        inner join Jet2Holidays.dbo.BusinessProcess bp on pjl.BusinessProcessId = bp.BusinessProcessId
            and bp.[Description] =  iif(@AllowNonSupportChanges = 0, 'CallCentreAction', bp.[Description]) 
        left outer join Jet2Holidays.dbo.PackageCostChangeLog pccl on pccl.PackageToJournalLinkId = pjl.PackageToJournalLinkId
        where pk.Reference = pp.PackageReference
        and pp.JournalID = pjl.JournalId

        ) as packageData
```

Your declared tabled will go out of scope in a similar manner to the way your non-global temporary table do.

Comment: Did you test that?  That select distinct * into `@PackageDataToProcess from `@ChangedData pp is not valid syntax.

Comment: @Frisbee I made a correction to the INSERT statement. Thanks.